# How can I clean up the lines of my watermark?

Tags: logo, png, image-editing

First time post so forgive me. I created my own logo to use as a watermark for my photos, I like the design but didn't have the technical skills to do it well. I sadly made it in paint. Some of the lines are not smooth and the edges all look rough, I assume it can be made to be a better quality. If possible I need it in Black, White and Grey. Again sorry I am new to this, I believe to use it as a watermark it needs to be a PNG and layered?

Thank you to everyone in advance.

[image: Tim Ward Photography Logo]

Comment: Hey Tim. If you're asking for help with implementation, please include what you've tried and why it didn't work with screenshots. Please edit your post with what your desired results are, what resources you referenced and why those didn't work. See [this meta post](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/699/request-new-close-reason-what-have-you-tried) for discussion and see [this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Hello Tim, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Your question reads like you want some of us to do the work for you. This is **not** the intent of this site. We are a Q&A site for anyone wanting to do graphic design themselves, and not a jobs posting forum. Please red the [help] to understand what this site is about. Thanks for understanding. For what it's worth, my main advice would be to get rid of the very, very tacky and cheap-looking typeface. The logo is decent, the text below it ruins it beyond belief. :)

Comment: We're not providers of design services

Comment: This is like us asking you "will you do free photography?"

Comment: Sorry for the miss understanding, I thought it was a reddit type community where people take on some small tasks for fun and practice. My apologizes.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the black-white design it's really easy to clean it up:
[These steps are written to be carried out in Photoshop]

- Remove text from layer
- Create path from logo symbol
- Change the path to whatever size you want (it's like a vector now)
- Fill the path with black

That's it. It would be smooth as flan.

[image]

Comment: OP used paint, so probably no photoshop. The GIMP (open source) may have/probably has all of these tools

Comment: Haven't really used Gimp, if it has a pen tool, then it can definitely be used.